# Docker postgrsql not connected in spring boot

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have used **docker-compose.yaml**. I have configured in docker-compose.yml bellow like:

**Step 1:**  In d**ocker-compose.yaml** I user bellow code

```
  services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        container_name: postgres
        hostname: postgres
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: accountdb
          
      account-opening:
        image: ehaque95/pocv1-account-opening:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        mem_limit: 700m
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        networks:
          - account-network
        depends_on:  
          - postgres    
        environment:
          SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/accountdb

    volumes:
      db-data:
```

**Step 2 :**

I have configure **applicaiton.yml**  in spring boot bellow like:

```
    spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/accountdb
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        database: postgresql
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        properties:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Note : postgresql server IP change frequently. When i run docker inpspect  ,it shows some **"IPAddress": "172.19.0.2"** or sometimes **"IPAddress": "172.19.0.3"**.It shows when I run **docker-compose up** again.

It shows connection error.what is the wrong of my code connect to postgresql. Please help me

Comment: Are you running the application in the same `docker-compose.yml` file?  You've named the database container `db` but you have `postgres:5432` in the URL.  (Also consider setting the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml`, rather than a Spring properties file, so that all of these deployment-specific names and settings are in the same place.)

Comment: @DavidMaze sorry for late reply. I modified  in docker-compose.yml file  but same error. I update my code . Please help me..

Comment: In the edit, the `account-opening` container has a `networks:` block, but `postgres` doesn't.  Does deleting all of the `networks:` blocks everywhere help?  (The database IP address changing on restart is normal, and you shouldn't need to look it up.)

Comment: @DavidMaze You are great. Two days I am working on the problem. Salute boss. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two containers to communicate with each other, they must be on the same Docker network.  [By default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it; if you specify other `networks:` for a container, then they are not attached to the `default` network.

In your `docker-compose.yml`, the `account-opening` container has a `networks:` block, but `postgres` doesn't:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    ...
    # no networks:, so implicitly
    # networks: [default]
  account-opening:
    ...
    networks: [account-network] # and not default
    # The postgres container is on the default network
    # This container is on account-network
    # And so this host name doesn't resolve
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/accountdb
```

There's nothing wrong with using the `default` network.  For most typical applications you can delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  Then the `default` network will get created with default settings, and all of the containers will attach to that network, and be able to address each other by their Compose service name.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/accountopendb
```

if you are running both the spring app and the postgresql container in the same machine in your datasource config.

Comment: `localhost` in Docker generally means "this container", not "this physical system" or "this Compose file".  You can't use `localhost` to connect between containers.